# PHP Is Not Loading Extensions

Tags: php, sql, web, php-extension

I am currently trying to get PHP to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server, but for some reason it will not load the php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts.dll & php_sqlsrv_80_ts.dll extensions. I have them in the ext folder, and have added the lines:

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_80_ts.dll

to the php.ini file.
Whenever I load my php info the modules do not show up. I have done this with a local server using XAMPP before and it worked perfectly fine. Currently I am trying to do this using a local Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard server, I have other extensions in the same folder that are loading just fine. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your output of phpinfo(); ??

Comment: Which HTTP server are you using, and have you restarted it after updating the PHP config? Also, have you verified that the php.ini that you edited is the one that's being used?